# Don't we need an axiom for $\omega_1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

As we needed an axiom to take the supremum of the finite ordinals, how are we allowed without another axiom to take the supremum of the countable ordinals?

Comment: Because we can just use [Hartogs' lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hartogs%27_Lemma_(Set_Theory)) on $\omega$ (if we already have $\omega$).